# dotnet is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, dotnet-cli, .net-core

We have downloaded and run `DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003133-x64.exe`. After having closed and reopened our command prompt, running `dotnet` gives the following output.

> The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

We have tried the following:

1. Uninstall all versions of Visual Studio.
2. Uninstall all versions of .NET Core.
3. Repair C++ Redistributable 2015 x86 & x64
4. Restart the computer.
5. Then reinstall the .NET Core SDK.

This is the contents of `C:/Program Files/dotnet`

```
host
  fxr
sdk
  1.0.0-preview2-003133
shared
  Microsoft.NETCore.App
swidtag
  Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2-003133 (x64).swidtag
```

Our PATH includes `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`

Comment: Did you solve this.  I am going through it now but on "1.0.1-preview3-004056" in VS2015.

Comment: @K7Buoy I did solve it, but I'm afraid I did not document the solution.

Comment: I had to roll back in my project.json to 1.0.0-preview2-003131.  Something messed my system up, I have been messing about with Gulp and Bash over the last couple of days and my PATH had been removed as well.  All sorts going on for some reason.

Comment: @K7Buoy I have since found a answer that works for us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After again coming across this problem, we [found the answer here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3571).

Open Programs and Features, choose Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86), click Uninstall and then choose Repair. After repairing it (and the x64 version if you have it), reinstall or repair the installation of the .NET Core SDK 1.0.1.

Answer (score 27):

Also ensure that `"C:\Program Files\dotnet"` is part of the "path" system environment variable.

After uninstalling previous SDK versions, it had disappeared from mine.

Comment: Restart IDE if restarting shell within it doesn't work.

Comment: The same happened for me. This is certainly a bug in the dotnet installer.

Comment: I had this happen after uninstalling visual studio 2022 (I use Rider). The actual SDK was still there but it was removed from the path.

Answer (score 21):

This error also occurs if .Net Core is not installed on your machine. To verify it, please run the command `dotnet --help` from Windows PowerShell or VS Code terminal. If .Net Core is installed then you will see the output, else the same error. If you see the same error then:

- Please [download and install it from here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).
- Then close the CLI or Code editor you are using.
- Re-open it again, run the following command:

  ```
  dotnet new webApp -o aspnetcoreapp
  ```

It will hopefully let you get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. It can be fixed by following this solution:

1. Open command window (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) then:

   ```
   cd Desktop
   mkdir CSharp
   cd CSharp
   ```
2. Open new file on desktop, then after that

   ```
   dotnet new console -o firstapp
   cd firstapp
   code
   ```

   vs code automatically opened.
3. Then you open the terminal:

   ```
   dotnet restore
   dotnet run
   ```

Finally done.

You can watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/Get-started-VSCode-Csharp-NET-Core-Windows).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue had to do with the *x64* vs. *x86* discrepancy.
My path had x86 in it. I manually changed it to "Program Files" rather than "Program Files (x86) and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apps and Features,
Search for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 
Click the modify button and then click repair, do this for both versions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015. It should then prompt you to restart device.
This worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Control Panel->Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable(x86)-> Repair. Following this completion, Microsoft .NET core SDK-> Repair. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was updating VS 2019 when it occurred. Once the update is finished, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell terminal as admin

Run these commands in sequence to troubleshoot as shown in the picture.

- dotnet --list-sdks
- winget search dotnet
- winget install --id Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.7 -e
- cd C:\"Program Files"\dotnet
- .\dotnet --list-sdks
- Restart the powershell terminal
- dotnet --list-sdks

[image]

Make sure Environment path is updated
[image]