# visual studio code change cli path

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am trying to make a completely portable .net core development environment. I have everything set up and portable except Visual Studio Code is looking for the dotnet cli in the default location on the c: drive. Can I change the path to the dotnet core sdk cli in Visual Studio Code and if so, where?

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8530

Comment: Unfortunately no. They are talking about the MSBuild process. I am just trying to get the dotnet new console command to execute without error. When I run the new command I get the following error:

dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet new console

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800519/8534630

Comment: Does not look like what I am trying to do is possible. If I have to modify anything on the host OS then it is not truly portable. I was hoping for a setting in Visual Studio Code pointing to the CLI but everything I am seeing involves changing settings on the host.

Comment: It is not VSCode, but the OmniSharp project that implements the C# support. Documentation seems to be sparse, so many times you need to dig the code base, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode or ask the developers.