# dotnet: Works from Windows 10 command prompt, but not in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am starting my journey into learning DotNet, and doing a demo application found on MS website, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-razor-pages-aspnet-core/3-exercise-create-new-aspnetcore-app.

I am getting the following error when trying to run dotnet in VSCode:

`The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`, but it works from command line.

Some information:

- When opening a command prompt in Windows 10 (Admin or non admin), or Windows PowerShell, `dotnet --help` is found and responds.
- The path to dotnet is set correctly for both my own user and also for the system account (just to be sure).
- The tools is set in my user path as follows: `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`.
- I tried PowerShell and Command Prompt both as Admin and regular user, to check if it is perhaps a user rights elevation issue that makes it fail in VSCode, but it is not. Both user types work outside VSCode.

As far as I can tell, everything is correct, and the answers here do not work for me: [dotnet is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568758/dotnet-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

My output when I do `dotnet --version` from the command prompt or PowerShell is:

```
C:\Users\bobandalice>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   6.0.100
Commit:    9e8b04bbff

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.19042
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 6.0.0
Commit:  4822e3c3aa

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

When doing the same in VSCode, the output is this:

```
PS C:\Users\bobandalice\OneDrive\dotnetapps\RazorPagesPizza> dotnet --info
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was  
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet --info
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotnet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Q: Have you tried uninstalling/re-installing .Net Core/.Net 5.x - including Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86) - on your workstation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42800519/421195

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have just tried that again, as well - still the same problem. I am using DotNet 6 though, not 5. Also - as I said, I can do everything I need to do from command line, but not from VSCode. This seems like the C# extension for VSCode that is having some config issue perhaps?

Comment: I love VSCode, and I use it daily.  But for C# development, I generally prefer using MSVS (MSVS Pro or MSVS Express) instead.  Q: Is that an option for you?

Comment: I can if I don't need an expensive license. I am not a DotNet developer, as you can see by the question. I am just learning for now. My biggest client is going to rewrite their enterprise system into DotNet in 3 years, and I need to be relevant by then. They will migrate away from CodeIgniter and PHP. I am starting to prepare only now.

Comment: I am installing MSVS Community 2022 now. Not going to address my question, but am open to test new things out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having same issue. I'm not sure if this is ideal but this is something I figured out that seems to work. In the File -> Settings -> Preferences -> Features -> Terminal, I changed my terminal to external from integrated and it fixed the problem. I may be switching to Visual Studio Community also, though.

[image: change terminal to external]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Mine is already set to integrated, but I will change it to External and then to Powershell, because it does work in Powershell, so that could possibly solve it. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you.  Don't know if this is the best solution but it most certainly works.  Thanks again.